# '[<ProfileController.ProfileModel 0x600000145c20> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key isExpanded.'

Tags: ios, swift3

I am not getting why is it crashing everything looks fine to me.On selecting table cell I get this crash -

**Model Class-:**

```
import UIKit

class ProfileModel: NSObject {
        var isExpandable:Bool!
        var isExpanded:Bool!
        var isVisible:Bool!
        var value:String!
        var primaryTitle:String!
        var secondryTitle:String!
        var cellIdentifier:String!
        var additionalRows:Int!
        init(isExpandable:Bool,isExpanded:Bool,isVisible:Bool,value:String,primaryTitle:String,secondryTitle:String,cellIdentifier:String,additionalRows:Int) {
            self.isExpanded = isExpanded
            self.isExpandable = isExpandable
            self.isVisible = isVisible
            self.value = value
            self.primaryTitle = primaryTitle
            self.secondryTitle = secondryTitle
            self.cellIdentifier = cellIdentifier
            self.additionalRows = additionalRows
        }

}
```

**Controller Class-:**

```
  var profileControllerData = [[ProfileModel]]()
     func loadProfileControllerData()
        {
            var row1 = [ProfileModel]()
            var row2 = [ProfileModel]()


            let firstObject = ProfileModel(isExpandable: true, isExpanded: false, isVisible: true, value:"" , primaryTitle: "Recent Look Book Curated For You:", secondryTitle: "", cellIdentifier: "Parent", additionalRows: 1)
            row1.append(firstObject)
            let secondObject = ProfileModel(isExpandable: false, isExpanded: false, isVisible: false, value: "false", primaryTitle: "", secondryTitle: "Expanded", cellIdentifier: "Child", additionalRows: 0)
            row1.append(secondObject)

            let personalInformation = ProfileModel(isExpandable: true, isExpanded: false, isVisible: true, value:"" , primaryTitle: "Personal Information:", secondryTitle: "", cellIdentifier: "Parent", additionalRows: 1)
            row2.append(personalInformation)
            let personalInformationChild = ProfileModel(isExpandable: false, isExpanded: false, isVisible: false, value: "false", primaryTitle: "", secondryTitle: "Expanded", cellIdentifier: "PersonalInformation", additionalRows: 0)
            row2.append(personalInformationChild)
            let essentials = ProfileModel(isExpandable: true, isExpanded: false, isVisible: true, value:"" , primaryTitle: "You must have essentials:", secondryTitle: "", cellIdentifier: "Parent", additionalRows: 1)


            profileControllerData.append(row1)
            profileControllerData.append(row2)
    }

     public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    let indexOfTappedRow = visibleRowsPerSection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        profileControllerData[indexPath.section][indexOfTappedRow].setValue(shouldExpandAndShowSubRows, forKey: "isExpanded")

// CRASH HERE
        }
```

**This is not my complete code I am just showing the issue part.All my classes are defined correctly and identifier are also correct.-:**

Comment: Why are the properties implicit unwrapped optional, but all passed values in the initializer are non-optional? **Never** declare properties IUO which are initialized via an `init` method. Remove all exclamation marks. And why do you use KVC rather than `item.isExpanded = shouldExpandAndShowSubRows`?

Comment: @vadian didn't get your last point can you show me how can I correct it the error?

Comment: I don't know if it corrects the error but use the property directly with dot notation rather than `setValue:forKey:`

Comment: @vadian i will try that and let you know.

Comment: @vadian thanks for the idea it worked.